# Get the next image in directory on clicking JButton - Swing

Tags: java, swing, gallery, jbutton

I am displaying an image on the screen now I want to press Jbutton and display the next image in that directory. And other button(previous) should display the previous image. All of it in a loop. So that first image is displayed after the last image of the directory. This is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

class ImageFilter extends FileFilter {

@Override
public boolean accept(File f) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        return true;
    }
    String name = f.getAbsolutePath();
    if (name.matches(".*((.jpg)|(.gif)|(.png))"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
    return "Image Files(*.jpg, *.gif, *.png)";
}

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class bottompanel extends JPanel {
JButton prev, next;

bottompanel() {
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "45%[center][center]", ""));

    prev = new JButton("Previous");
    next = new JButton("Next");
    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        }
    });
    this.add(prev, " w 100!");
    this.add(next, "w 100!");
}
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class imgpanel extends JPanel {
imgpanel(JLabel image) {
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "", ""));
    this.add(image, "push,align center");
}
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DispImg extends JFrame {
JMenuBar jmenubar;
JMenu jmenu;
JMenuItem jopen, jexit;
JLabel image;
BufferedImage img, dimg;

DispImg() {

    // initializing the Frame
    this.setTitle("Display Test");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[fill,grow]", "[]push[]"));
    this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);

    // create label
    image = new JLabel(" ");
    //add label to panel
    this.add(new imgpanel(image), "wrap");

    //add buttons to bottompanel
    this.add(new bottompanel(), "gaptop 10");

    // Making Menubar
    jmenubar = new JMenuBar();
    jmenu = new JMenu("File");
    jopen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    jopen.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    KeyStroke key1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, Event.CTRL_MASK);
    jopen.setAccelerator(key1);
    jopen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setFileFilter(new ImageFilter());
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(file);
                    float width = img.getWidth();
                    float height = img.getHeight();
                    if (img.getHeight() > 500 && (width / height) > 1) {
                        Image thumb = img.getScaledInstance(-1, 620,
                                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(thumb));
                    } else if (img.getHeight() > 500
                            && (width / height) <= 1) {
                        Image thumb = img.getScaledInstance(460, -1,
                                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(thumb));
                    } else {
                        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    jexit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    jexit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    jmenu.add(jopen);
    jmenu.addSeparator();
    jmenu.add(jexit);
    jmenubar.add(jmenu);
    this.setJMenuBar(jmenubar);
}

public static void main(String s[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new DispImg();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `"This is my code so far:..."` -- OK, so what is your *specific* question? So far as written your question is little more than a "code dump", a "here's my code, please fix it". To get a better answer, please outline all details that you're precisely stuck on. We do better at answering questions, not fixing code.

Comment: For one, tell us *what is wrong* with your current code, *what is missing*, what errors you may be seeing,...

Comment: Don't know how to fetch the next image from the directory. when i added actionListener() on next button nothing happened and the new image is not displayed. No exceptions were generated, pressing next/previous should display to and fro images but that's not happening.

Answer (score 2):

> when i added actionListener() on next button nothing happened and the new image is not displayed

You don't have any code in the actionListener, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen.

> Don't know how to fetch the next image from the directory

You would probably use the JFileChooser to select the directory (and maybe initial image to display).

Once you have the directory then you could use the `File.listFiles(...)` method to get a list of all the image files in the directory. Then your Next/Previous button would add/subtract one to access the next/previous File in the array.